# Float Elements next/below to each other

Tags: html, css

My Code http://jsfiddle.net/p796z/1/

**HTML**

```
 <div class="box1"> 
    <p>Content Content</p>
    <p>Content Content</p>
    <p>Content Content</p>
</div>

<div class="box2"> 
    <p>Content Content</p>
</div>

<div class="box2"> 
    <p>Content Content Content Content Content Content</p>
</div>

<div class="box2"> 
    <p>Content Content</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box1 { background:red; float:left; width:50% }
.box2 { background:yellow; float:left; width:25%; }
```

As it can be seen from the example above the third yellow box is below other boxes but leaves these empty space between the first yellow box, because the second yellow box is having bigger height. My question is how can I make that the third yellow box comes after the first yellow box no matter what is the height of the second yellow box.

Comment: In general you can't do this with floats. Try looking into **masonry.js**

Comment: Isotope.js do the some

Comment: Isotope.js do the some

Comment: Can you put the smaller boxes into three columns?

Comment: using jquery make all box2 height the same as the max height of box2, and probably you might group the box2 divs in one container div.

Comment: masonry.js works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not strictly limited to the HTML above, you can wrap the first .box2 divs in another div, and float that instead. Give it 25% width. You can see an example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/LcM7A/

```
.box1 { background:red; float:left; width:50% }
.box2 { background:yellow; float:left; width:25%; }
.box3{ float:left; width:25%; }
.box4 { background:yellow; float:left; width:100%; }

<div class="box1"> 
    <p>Box 1</p>
    <p>Content Content</p>
    <p>Content Content</p>
</div>

<div class="box3">
    <div class="box4"> 
        <p>Box 4</p>
        <p>Content Content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box4"> 
        <p>Box 4</p>
        <p>Content Content Content Content Content Content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box2"> 
    <p>Box 2</p>
    <p>Content Content</p>
</div>
```